# How to map query parameters with dashes in their names

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

Is there a way to map the query string parameter `my-param` to the controller method parameter `myParam` in Web API 2 (preferably using attribute routing)?

This means a URI like...

```
library.com/books?search-text=REST
```

...should be routed to the controller method

```
[HttpGet, Route("books/{search-text?}")]
public IEnumerable<Book> Get(string searchText = "") { ... }
```

Is this possible? The [Microsoft documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) does not provide an example for that case. But it also doesn't provide some kind of grammar for route parameters, hence I'm not sure if it's exhaustive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `[FromUri]` attribute as follows:

`[FromUri(Name = "search-text")]`

You weren't far off with your comment. If you need this as a convention you can likely create your own parameter binding in Web API:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api